# Display friendly field values in SharePoint 2010 list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, external-content-type

I have an SQL table where I with the help of an Externl Content Type has created a list in SharePoint 2010. The table has a foreign key to a dim table where the display friendly names are listed. How do i get these names displayed as the value in the columns of my list instead of the foreign key value?

I have already managed to get this changed in the picker but have so far not been able to find a solution for displaying the names in the columns.

[image]

Display friendly names in the picker

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view in sql which will contain friendly display name. Then create external content type based on the view.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but unfortunately the view will not allow me to update the records displayed in the list